# What are the downsides of using IPv6 Multicast for all communication?

Tags: routes, ipv6, multicast

Given IPv6 Multicast allows for a sub-pub communication model, it seems like a no-brainer for the vast majority of communication, but its very rarely used beyond video streaming, and I'd like to know if this is because its only efficient for large groups or if its just because its not well understood and Unicast/Anycast are easier to implement?

Unicast addresses are still needed to send to the Multicast group addresses, but even for groups of 2, Multicast seems like it would theoretically be more efficient and flexible because either party can leave the group at any time.

One issue may be the state requirements needed to maintain the sets of subscribers, but so long as packet duplication is performed at the edge of the network if required, I don't see how this adds that much overhead?

I also understand there are some current limitations with regard to support for globally scoped IPv6 Multicast, but this question is more about the theory and trade-offs with using IPv6 Multicast in place of Unicast.

Please let me know what I'm missing or provide some links to material I can read to get a better understanding of what would be required and what the trade-offs are

Thank you

I've implemented IPv6 multicast on my local network and sent packets globally between my home and my office, and it works fantastically well, so I'm wondering what the drawbacks are for using it in most contexts

Comment: Multicast cannot be used on the public Internet (you can multicast in a tunnel between sites, but that requires a unicast tunnel), and you cannot use TCP with multicast because TCP creates a peer connection between two devices.

Comment: Thanks for your response -- and yes, I know Multicast can't be used reliably with a global scope 'E' yet,, but my question is moreso about the downsides of using it even for 1-to-1 communication if it was reliable at the global scope

Comment: You still cannot use it with TCP because TCP needs to create a connection. Multicaswt cannot be used as a source address, so trying to create a TCP connection between a source unicast address and a destination multicast address will not work because the other side will need to use a source unicast address that will not match the destination address of the initiating host. A TCP connection is identified by both the source and destination IP and TCP addresses. Sending a SYN to a multicast address will get a SYN/ACK back from a different (unicast) address that will result in a RST.

Comment: Yes, for sure -- it's encouraging that HTTP3 will use UDP, but my question is more about a technical comparison of Unicast/Anycast to Multicast -- other than current support, would there be any downside to replace the majority of Unicast/Anycast communication with Multicast?